# CNAME CDN Record Testing

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, cname

Is there any issues to modifying the **CNAME** for **cdn.abc.com** to point to **cloudfront.abc.com** instead of the **Cloudflare** domain?

Is there way to altering the **hosts file** to test in windows environment .

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you asking how to use your own domain name with Amazon CloudFront? If so, see: [Using custom URLs by adding alternate domain names (CNAMEs) - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run a `dig` command on the hostname you want to test against and add the resulting IP address in your hosts file with the public hostname.